# Passing < and > as literal arguments in bash

Tags: bash

How to pass to the script the sign of the comparison operation as a commandline argument when run in the console?

Comment: maybe something like `[ "$1" -eq  ">"  ] && [ "$a" -gt "$b" ] `

Comment: @TheFool, `-eq` is only for numeric comparisons; it'll throw an error when given `>` as an argument. You want `=` as the operator (note: not `==`, which is a nonstandard extension) to do a string comparison -- see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to pass to the script the sign of the comparison operation as an argument when run in the console?

To disable special meaning of `>` `<` as redirection operators, quote or escape them.

```
echo '<' '>'
echo \< \>
```